# How to prove the convergence of an integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: integration

I know the integral of $$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \dfrac{1}{(1+\Vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\Vert)^2\Vert\mathbf{y}\Vert^2} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$$ converges for any $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Would someone help me prove the bound of integral is independent of $x$? i.e. $$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \dfrac{1}{(1+\Vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\Vert)^2\Vert\mathbf{y}\Vert^2} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}\leq C$$ where $C$ is independent of $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Do you mean $$\displaystyle\iiint_{R^3} \dfrac{1}{(1+|x-y|)^2|y|^2} dxdydz$$

Comment: Fubini + translation invariance of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: No, I mean $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Proving a bound does not depend on x does not mean the value of the integral does not depend on x.

Comment: Thank you very much! I make an error of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to prove when $|x|>1$.

$\quad\displaystyle\iiint_{R^3} \dfrac{|x|}{(1+|x-y|)^2|y|^2} dy = \iiint_{R^3} \dfrac{|x|}{(1+|y|)^2|x-y|^2} dy \\\displaystyle= \iiint_{R^3} \dfrac{1}{(\frac 1{|x|}+|z|)^2|\frac x{|x|}-z|^2} dz \le \iiint_{R^3} \dfrac{1}{|z|^2|\vec{1}-z|^2} dz$.